# Can “of" be removed from "of whose" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> I once knew a former woman of easy virtue **of** whose past life there remained only a daughter who was almost as beautiful as the mother had once been, from The Lady of the Camellias.

This is my understanding:

> I once knew a (former woman of easy virtue) whose past life....

Comment: No: "of" cannot be dropped, To do so would render the sentence ungrammatical. The relative clause  "of whose past life there remained only a daughter ... " modifies the nominal "former woman of easy virtue". Within the relative clause the genitive (possessive) NP "whose past life there remained only a daughter ..." is complement of the prep "of", which explains why "of" cannot be dropped.

Comment: Is your question part of a homework assignment?

Comment: The Lady of the Camellias by Dumas is a translation. Are you translating it? Or criticizing a translation?

Comment: J'ai connu une ancienne femme galante à qui il ne restait plus de son passé qu'une fille presque aussi belle que, au dire de ses contemporains, avait été sa mère. That's the French and **it seems that ChatGPT or whatever automatic translation program has translated ancienne as former**.  What a hoot.

Comment: @Lambie I think so. The English version comes from my reading assignment.

Comment: Yes, well, it ends up being quite funny. A former woman. And it makes no sense to criticize the grammar of something that is a literally translated literary work.

Comment: @Lambie - _Ancien/ne_ can mean 'former' as well as 'ancient' in French.

Comment: It's not funny at all. The adjective "former" is modifying the whole idiomatic nominal "woman of easy virtue".

Comment: @KateBunting It doesn't mean "former woman (ancienne femme) of easy virtue", for pete's sake. It means she **used to be a woman of easy virtue**. So, the translation former woman of easy virtue is a hoot. Here's another (semi-ok) translation: "I knew an aged woman who had once been “gay,” whose only link with the past was a daughter almost as beautiful as she herself had been." Translator: Sir Edmond Gosse  https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1608/1608-h/1608-h.htm ancien professeur, ministre, président: former teacher, president, minister, sure https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A1686

Comment: There is no point in analyzing a bad translation from the French.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I once knew a former woman of easy virtue of whose past life there remained only a daughter who was almost as beautiful as the mother had once been.

Let's look at a context that contains a sentence with an analogous structure.

> Few paintings survived the high waters of the flood.
>
> Little of the art collection remained.

"Little" refers to a portion of the "art collection"  just as in your original sentence, "a daughter" is a "piece" of the woman's past life.

Now let's make a sentence with a relative clause:

> They beheld the water damage to the art collection, *of which little remained.*

**of** preserves the idea of a "piece" or "portion":  *little of the art collection*. We can't say this:

> They beheld the water damage to the art collection, which little remained.

Comment: Can't "a former woman of easy virtue" taken as a whole, like a noun? My understanding is something like "a former woman of easy virtue's past life remained only a daughter". But I do know that it may sound a bit weird.

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird by adding another "of" before "whose", when the "whose" itself sometimes can be equivalent to "of whom" or "of which".

Comment: **whose** specifies the "owner" of the past life.   **of** identifies/connects an element or piece of that past life.   "....a person, little of whose past life remains".  The past life belongs to the person.  Little is what remains of the past life. (little belonging to the past life that belongs to the person remains)

Comment: You are misunderstanding how **remained** is used.  You are using it like "contained". "whose past life contained only a daughter".    But *a daughter* is the SUBJECT of the verb **remained**.  "of whose past life only a daughter survived".  I suspect that the verb-subject word order is throwing you off in "... of whose past life there remained only a daughter".  It is "**there** remained only a daughter".

Comment: Only a daughter remained.    There remained only a daughter.  Only a daughter survived.  There survived only a daughter.

Comment: @ TimR Yes.  I think you are right. I am just way too confused with the correct order of the sentence.

Comment: @ TimR So "There remained only a daughter" is some kind of an inversion? Not sure what "there" is supposed to mean here. But I can see that "remained" in this case is used as an intransitive verb. And the "daughter" is the subject instead of the object. So the sentence can be done like this? "Of whose past life only a daughter remained." And "of" is actually put behind "remained"? "only a daughter remained of whose past life" So the final version is "only a daughter remained of the woman's past life." ? Not quite sure.

Comment: **whose** is a relative so it cannot be used like this:  "only a daughter remained of whose past life". But you are connect that **remain** is intransitive. And correct that with **there** constructions the verb follows **there**.  "There" in such constructions is often called  a "dummy" subject. @BillJ would be able to give the you CGEL terminology for this.  And looking down the page, I see that he has.

Comment: @MTMTESK "There" is the dummy subject of the _there_ clause. Sorry for the interjection!

Comment: @BillJ Thanks again. I am getting so close at understanding this structure. But I still have some queries. 1. What is the antecedent of 'whose'—'a former woman of easy virtue' or 'a former woman'?" actually. I believe it is the latter. 2. And the second part of sentence shouldn't go like "only a daughter remained of the past life of the woman", the same as "only a daughter remained in the past life of the woman". But you said something about whose is a relative. I don' know.

Comment: I won't address the question of whether the antecedent includes its modifier "of easy virtue" but bear in mind that there is a main independent clause and a relative clause that cannot stand on its own, and if you remove the relative as you're doing ("only a daughter remained of the past life **of the woman**") you are breaking that clause structure.  That is a valid paraphrase of the meaning but not a substitute for the clause structure.

Comment: @TimR I am sorry about that. I am breaking it down because I am trying to make it clearer to me. I am not sure whether this is the issue that remain is not a transitive verb that can connect directly with the past life. "Of whose past life only a daughter remained". Now I can see why "of" shouldn't be dropped. But it is ok to replace "of" with other prepositions like "from" or "in"?

Comment: @TimR I see. Now I get why "of" should be there. And by using an inversion like “there remained only a daughter" can make daughter become the antecedent of the incoming clause. Thanks again for your patience and time.

Comment: **remain** is intransitive for sure.  **from** would work, but **in** would not.  It is her "past life" that is being spoken of, and "in" would make it a present life because of present-tense **remains**.   "I was a gladiator in a former life, and all that remains in that life is a trident."  You'd have to say "of that life" or "from that life".

Comment: Sorry, needed to make an edit to the last comment and exceeded the 5-minute limit and deleted it and reposted the edited version.

Comment: @MTMTESK Sorry, but you still have the analysis wrong. There is no inversion in the clause "there remained only a daughter". This is called a presentational clause where "there" is a dummy subject and the verb phrase "remained only a daughter" is the predicate. The preposed bit in the sentence is "of whose past life" (where "whose" refers to 'a former woman of easy virtue') which in the basic (non-preposed) version would occur in post-verbal position.

Comment: @ BillJ ok thanks. So it is not an inversion.

Comment: @MTMTESK That is correct. The pronoun "there" is the subject, so there is no inversion. If there was inversion, "a daughter" would be the subject, but that is not the case. Does that clear things up?

Comment: @BillJ It doesn't clear things up for me :-)  If "there" is considered the grammatical subject in "presentation" clauses, why does the verb  agree in number with whatever occupies the slot after the verb?  If this were a present-tense presentation clause, and all that remained were two daughters, it would be "... there **remain** only two daughters".  Is some kind of "spooky action at a distance" entanglement causing **there** to become plural?

Comment: @TimR So the sentence is an inversion with "there" being the dummy subject?

Comment: @TimR Quote what you said, “Only a daughter remained. There remained only a daughter." I still have a query, Does "there" always disappear when you prepose "only a daughter", since it is a dummy subject.

Comment: @MTMTEST: Yes, you would say "... of that former life **only a daughter remained** and "there" would not be used.

Answer (score 1):

> *I once knew a former woman of easy virtue* [*of whose past life there*
> *remained only a daughter who was almost as beautiful as ...*].

No: "of" cannot be dropped, To do so would render the sentence ungrammatical.

The bracketed relative clause modifies the nominal "former woman of easy virtue". Within the relative clause the genitive (possessive) noun phrase "whose past life there remained only a daughter ..." is complement of the preposition "of", which explains why "of" cannot be dropped.

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird by adding another "of" before "whose", when the "whose" itself sometimes can be equivalent to "of whom" or "of which".

Comment: @MTMTESK Not at all. It was the past life **of** "a former woman of easy virtue" that  is being talked of in the _there_ clause.

Comment: "Whose past life" is the past life _of_ the woman, but the sentence is about what remains _of_ that life.

Comment: @MTMTESK The _there_ clause complicates the grammar somewhat. The expression "of whose past life" is preposed from its 'basic' position at the end of the sentence, where it would be difficult to process. Think of it as meaning "only a daughter remained of the woman's past life". For we native speakers of English, just saying the sentence out loud without the "of" tells us it's ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ Can I break down the sentence into two parts? 1. I once knew a former woman of easy virtue. 2. the past life of the woman of easy virtue there (=past event?) remained only a daughter. So "of" is attached behind "there"? Is that why "of" should not be ignored? I am still quite confused.

Comment: @MTMTESK No: see my last comment.

Comment: @BillJ Could you help me with breaking down the original sentence? I think I am a bit confused with two "ofs" and "there". a former woman of easy virtue and a former woman [of whose past life there] ?

Comment: @MTMTESK "I once knew a former woman of easy virtue" + "the only remains of her past life was a daughter".

Comment: Incidentally, "there" is the 'dummy' subject of the clause "there remained only a daughter". It's called a presentational clause. The preposed bit is "of whose (her) past life". Are you clear now?

Comment: @BillJ "the only remains of her past life was a daughter" I think in this part "remain" is served as a noun? But in the original sentence, remain should be a verb right? So is there  a collocation for something like remain(V)+of? I still don't really know what "of" means here.